# How do I serve socket.io over HTTPS with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

**The problem:**

I just successfully got my Node.js server all working properly and setup with SSL, great. But then I see this:

> [blocked] The page at 'https://www.mywebsite.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but ran insecure content from
>   'http://54.xxx.xxx.77:4546/socket.io/socket.io.js': this content
>   should also be loaded over HTTPS.

I tried just changing the socket.io URL to `https`, but of course that doesn't work because socket.io insists on serving it's own generated file, a process that I don't think I control. I can change the port that socket.io listens on, that's it.

**The question:**

*So how do I securely serve socket.io (1.0)?*

**The codez:**

```
var port = 4546;

var io = require('/node_modules/socket.io')(port);
```

---

As a side note, I think socket.io (its back and forth communication) should run over HTTPS properly without any extra work; I read that somewhere. Perhaps someone can confirm. It is important that the web socket's communications be securely transferred.

Comment: This would be a really simple matter if I could just host my own copy of client-side socket.io to be served like the rest of my files, but I'm told that's a bad practice.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237184/how-to-configure-socket-io-to-run-on-same-port-on-https?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is [one of those occasions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213976/should-i-mark-as-duplicate-if-the-question-is-answered-elsewhere-but-its-not-t) where the questions aren't quite duplicates, but [the selected answer to a question answers this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24374974/3818284).

It's simple: Just pass your https server object as socket.io's port parameter.

> ```
> // ... require stuff
> var app = express();
>
> // ... set up your express middleware, etc
>
> var server = https.createServer(sslOptions, app);
> // attach your socket.io server to the express server
> var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
> server.listen(port);
> ```
>
> code by [aembke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2966874/aembke)