# How to handle 400 Not Found for "GET /socket.io/socket.io.js"?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

In my html file, i write this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Socket.io - System Monitor</title>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Socket.io - System Monitor</h1>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="/javascripts/monitor.js" type='text/javascript'></script>

<div id="node">
    <input type="text" id="host" name="host" value="http://localhost"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="startup()" value="OK"/>
</div>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="/javascripts/highcharts/highcharts.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="/javascripts/highcharts/modules/exporting.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the server side,

```
var app = express();
// starting http  servers
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I think every thing is right, but this is an error `404 not found` for "/socket.io/socket.io.js".

Comment: The error means that socket.io.js file not found in your client code. Check whether there is a folder socket.io at the same level as 'javascripts' folder within which socket.io.js file present.

Comment: Yes, in know the error's means, but i have install socket.io successfully.

Comment: You'll either want to serve/request the markup from the same server or specify a full URL. A path starting with `/` will use the same host as the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code.

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express()
, http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Your solution is right, but i have some doublt. I change `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` to `<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`, then i can access `socket.io.js` successfully. But why i can't use port `3000`?

Comment: Another question: The web server and socket.io can use the same port?

Comment: sincerely i don't know if its possible run https web server and socket io server on the same port, so i research a little bit to trying to figure out your question, and find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237184/how-to-configure-socket-io-to-run-on-same-port-on-https tell me if works